# Calculate count of rows matching a condition in a pandas frame (if possible using sortedness of the data)

Tags: python, pandas

**Dataset Description:**

I have a dataset that looks like this (sorted by key, which also means it is sorted by offset_time_stamp):

```
key       offset_time_stamp       person          7_sec_count
1         0                       A               0
2         0                       B               0
3         0                       A               1
4         1                       A               2
5         2                       B               1
6         7                       A               1
7         9                       B               0
```

Number of rows is around 20 million. Number of unique persons is around 4 million (each person having records ranging from 0 to 10k+ in the past 7 seconds).

I want to count the number of rows that appear for that person in the past 7 seconds (as calculated using the `offset_time_stamp`

**Here is what I tried:**

```
def get_count(x):
  return [data[the_condition].count() for row in x.iterrows()]

counts = data.groupby(person).apply(get_count)
```

This code ran in around 6 hours. I wanted to resample with 1 second, but it wasn't working as the dataset has several rows for the same person in that second - and I don't have micro-second level data. I need to resolve ties when timestamps are same by using the key value.

**What I want to do now?**

I now want to re-run the same exercise with 100 million rows and increasing the 7 second window to 7000 seconds. *The existing code is estimated to run in 5 days.*

How to make this calculation faster? I would love it to complete running in 2-3 hours, so I can analyze even larger datasets. I am OK with porting the solution to another language or use a purely numpy based solution instead of pandas.

**Can I also use the sortedness nature of the data?** I tried cumcount after grouping by person and subtracting the cumcount of the last row just falling outside the 7 second window. It was taking too long, probably because of the way I wrote it:

```
data_cumcount = data.groupby(person).cumcount() + 1

def get_subtractor(current_ts, person, index):
    global data_cumcount
    to_consider = sorted(person_level_indices[person][:person_level_indices[person].index(index)], reverse=True)
    for index in to_consider:
        if data_dict[index] <= current_ts: # -7 was already done and passed to this function
            return data_cumcount[index]
    return 0

def get_count(x):
    global data_cumcount
    return data_cumcount[x.name] - get_subtractor(x[TIME_STAMP]-7, x[person], x.name) - 1

counts = data.apply(get_count, axis=1)
```

I am guessing that the for loop in get_subtractor is causing it to take a lot of time in this approach.

I have tried a few other approaches, including recursing, but `data.groupby(person).apply(get_count)` is the one that performed the best given my seemingly not so efficient code.

Comment: What is `the_condition` in `data[the_condition]`?

Comment: `[[x[(x[KEY] < i[KEY]) & (x[TIME_STAMP] > i[TIME_STAMP]-7)][TIME_STAMP].count()] for n, i in x.iterrows()]` - basically whatever I explained in the past 7 seconds, after breaking ties (excluding the current row)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Using the sortedness of the timestamps as suggested, and the fact that `searchsorted` is vectorised, I was able to cut the execution time in 3.

```
def get_count(dfg):
    return pd.Series(
        np.arange(len(dfg)) - dfg.offset_time_stamp.searchsorted(dfg.offset_time_stamp - 6),
        index=dfg.index
    )

df['count'] = df.groupby('person').apply(get_count).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Note that [`searchsorted`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html) returns not the index of the series but the position in the underlying `numpy` array. As a result, the count is simply the difference between the current position (i.e. `np.arange`) and the position returned by `searchsorted`.

There is an overhead to convert the results to a series, but I need it to reassign the results at the end. If you find a way of using the `numpy` values directly, you can cut the time in half again.

---

**Original answer:**

There probably is a solution along the lines you mentioned with `cumcount`, but in the meantime this could already be faster:

```
def get_count(dfg):
    return dfg.apply(lambda row: dfg[dfg.offset_time_stamp > row['offset_time_stamp'] - 7].loc[:row.name-1].count(), axis=1)

df.groupby('person').apply(get_count)
```

I use native slicing and selecting instead of your `iterrows` loop. Note that when applying a function row-wise to a dataframe, `row.name` is the original dataframe's index.

Comment: Did you mean to say this? 


`return dfg.apply(lambda row: dfg[dfg.offset_time_stamp > row['offset_time_stamp'] - 7].loc[:row.name-1].count(), axis=1)`

Comment: BTW this one is running with similar speed as my `iterrows` solution. At an overall level, the difference in run-time was 1 second (`iterrows` performed better), for 2 million rows.

Comment: @srey123 you're right, I've edited my answer. Since your code is not reproducible as is, I did not benchmark the performance of my solution. Don't forget to include reproducible code in your questions.

Comment: Yep. Would have otherwise done that, but this piece of code has too many dependencies in terms of variables. So just wrote handpicked lines of code here. +1 for the native slicing bit.

Comment: @srey123 I found a solution based on `searchsorted` that cuts the time by half, are you interested?

Comment: Absolutely. Cutting down the time by half translates to saving hours of run-time :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115951/discussion-between-srey123-and-ians).